# Gödel's incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic

That thing that bugs me about Gödel. [From the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_incompleteness_theorems):

> If $p$ were provable, then $\operatorname{Bew}(G(p))$ would be provable, as argued above. But $p$ asserts the negation of $\operatorname{Bew}(G(p))$. Thus the system would be inconsistent, proving both a statement and its negation. **This contradiction shows that p cannot be provable.**

Why? Why not simply stop before the 'This'-sentence and simply conclude that the system is inconsistent? No idea.

Comment: The assumption is that ***p*** is provable. The contradiction shows that the assumption is false. The last statement is therefore true. It is the point of that step of the proof, so it needs to be stated.

Comment: I still don't see it. Assume **p** is provable. Derive that **not p** is provable. Tada: System is inconsistent. Done.

Comment: "System is inconsistent" is not the logical end of the proof. In a mathematical proof (and logic generally), when an assumption leads to "inconsistent" conclusions, you have proven that the assumption is false. This is called ["proof by contradiction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) and is a common technique for proving a theorem. You assume the opposite of what you want to prove, then demonstrate that your assumption results in a contradiction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematical proofs by contradiction, not programming.

Comment: P.S. Keep in mind that you are reading Wikipedia, which is not always clear or even accurate. Just because a Wikipedia entry says something in a certain way does not make that the best way to express the concept.

Comment: No. I think I got it. You need to assume both consistency and a notion that unprovable sentences exist.

Comment: @Marco Basically, it's just saying that the system can't be both consistent and complete (i.e. without unprovable sentences). And we're _pretty_ sure it's consistent — it's generally accepted that if you prove something it's true.

Comment: We cannot conclude that the system is inconsistent, because we do not know that $p$ is provable. We assumed, hypothetically, that $p$ could be provable, and from that derived that the system would be inconsistent. Therefore, because the system is *not* inconsistent, $p$ must *not* be provable - our hypothetical assumption must have been wrong.

Comment: See [Indirect proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

Comment: @Mauro. I get proof by contradiction. But Godel _derived_ a contradiction and _used_ that to conclude (only way out), since he assumed his system is consistent, the statement must be unprovable. I didn't know he assumed consistency and I actually think that is somewhat lacking from the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Of course you have to assume consistency. If the system is inconsistent, then everything including $p$, is provable. If I remember right, Godel's original proof assumed $\omega$-consistency, which is stronger than consistency.

Comment: Ah. I figured out I misread the presentation of the Wikipedia style proof. It somewhat suggested, well to me, a different interpretation than what was meant mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

In [indirect proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), we assume a "fact" : $\phi$, derive a contradiction : $\bot$ and then apply the "rule for indirect proof" :

> if $\Gamma,\phi \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \phi$,

to conclude with the negation of the assumed "fact".

In  Gödel's proof, we assume the "fact" : "$p$ is *provable*", then derive a contradiction [specifically, the fact that the system is inconsistent, because it proves both $\operatorname{Bew}(G(p))$ and $\lnot \operatorname{Bew}(G(p))$ ] and conclude with the negation of the "fact" : "$p$ is provable", i.e. we conclude with "$p$ is *unprovable*".

The proof has other "background" assumptions : the set $\Gamma$ of formulae of the "abstract" formulation of the rule.

In Gödel's proof, $\Gamma$ includes (among others) the fact that the system is *consistent*. Why so ? Because if the system is inconsistent then, by a well-know result of logic, it proves every formula: thus, an inconsistent system is trivially *complete*.

The correct formulation of [Gödel's [first] Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is :

> Any consistent formal system $F$ within which a certain amount of elementary arithmetic can be carried out is *incomplete*; i.e., there are statements of the language of $F$ which can neither be proved nor disproved in $F$.

In this formulation, we have to note the "assumption" :

- it applies to a *formal system* [and thus, **not** necessarily to "other constructs", like e.g. the human mind]
- the formal system must have a [formally specifiable] capibility : to be able to manage "a certain amount" of arithmetic
- the formal system must be *consistent*.

Thus, the conclusion proved by Gödel's proof is not an "absolute" one : it holds in the "context" specified by the previous "background" assumptions.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for your answer. It still somewhere bugs me that Godel derives an inconsistency, an indirect proof, to arrive at incompleteness but it all seems very plausible to me now. I must have had a blocking moment. Thanks for your answer, I would upvote if I could but I don't have the credits yet.